# Read Flink latency tracking metric in Datadog

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, datadog

I'm following this doc https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/ops/metrics/#end-to-end-latency-tracking and enabled metrics.latency.interval in flink-conf.yaml as shown below:

```
metrics.latency.interval: 60000
metrics.latency.granularity: operator
```

Now, I have the following questions:

1. how could I know what kind of metrics(a list of metrics name) are enabled? I didn't find any in metrics UI.
   [image]
2. Datadog is my reporter, will the latency metrics send to Datadog just like other system metrics listed here https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/flink/#data-collected? If yes, what's their name? If no, is there anything I need to do to get them in Datadog?

I'm new to the Flink and the Datadog.Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can access these metrics via rest api integration:

```
http://{job_manager_address}:8081/jobs/{job_id}/metrics
```

which will return:

```
[
  {
    "id": "latency.source_id.3d28eee20f19966ad0843c8183e96045.operator_id.9c9bbdbebfd61a4aaac39e2c417a4f21.operator_subtask_index.7.latency_min"
  },
  {
    "id": "latency.source_id.bca0e5ddee87a6f64a26077804c63e69.operator_id.197249262ed30764bb323b65405e10b4.operator_subtask_index.14.latency_p75"
  },
  {
    "id": "latency.source_id.bca0e5ddee87a6f64a26077804c63e69.operator_id.b9d4ed4c91fec482427d3584100b1c90.operator_subtask_index.12.latency_median"
  },
]
```

This means that latency from the source_id 3d28eee20... to operator_id 9c9bbdbe with subtask index 7.

However I don't know exact meaning of the `latency_p75 or latency_min`. Maybe someone else can help us both.

Answer (score 1):

@monstero has explained where to find the latency metrics -- they are job metrics.

The latency metrics are histogram metrics. latency_p75, for example, is the 75th percentile latency, meaning that 75% of the time the latency was less than the reported value.

In all, you can access the min, max, mean, median, stddev, p75, p90, p95, p98, p99, and p999.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, I am confused =>  ".. 75th percentile latency, meaning that 75% of the time the latency was less than the reported value."  these metrics return json object {id: "latency.source...", value:"251"}. According to the you said, only 25 % of the collected metrics took time more than 251 (ms or s whatever) (then latency is %25 ??). Or 75 % of the collected metrics took time more than 251 (ms or s whatever)??

Comment: The sampling occurs in batches of some duration (1 sec, I believe). If the p75 value for one batch is 251ms, then 75% of the samples during that batch were less than 251ms (and 25% were greater).